# 404 when load bootstrap-italia

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-5

I need to load a botstrap-italia CSS. I install bootstrap-italia and I when I run the server I do this:

```
ng build --watch --base-href /home/
```

I have just installed bootstrap-italia, it is in my node module, so I import css in this way:
(in my index.html):

I do:

```
<link href="../node_module/bootstrap-italia/dist/css/bootstrap-italia.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It creates this link:

http://localhost:8080/node_modules/bootstrap-italia/dist/css/bootstrap-italia.min.css

in node module there is the path but it gives me 404.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The css needs to be added using the angular.json file to be available to be used into the project.

Go to `angular.json` file inside your project then add this link in the array of styles that you can find in it.

```
  "styles": [
    "node_module/bootstrap-italia/dist/css/bootstrap-italia.min.css"
]
```

Then it should work